# javax.faces.model.NoRowAvailableException on primefaces data grid component

Tags: jsf, primefaces, managed-bean

I am trying to make a task board using panels (with task information) inside data grids (representing task states) where one panel can be dragged from a data grid and dropped into another. When I run the application, this only works the first time I drag a panel and drop into other data grid, the second time I try this, the panel doesn't bind to the destination data grid. If I refresh the page and try again, the panel binds to the destination data grid but the server shows a javax.faces.model.NoRowAvailableException. Why am i getting this exception? Here is the code:

home.xhtml:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

<h:head></h:head>
<h:body>

    <h:form id="form">
        <h:inputText id="newTaskName" />
        <h:inputText id="newTaskDescription" />
        <p:selectOneListbox id="newTaskState"
            value="#{taskView.newTaskState}">
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="TODO" itemValue="1" />
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="DOING" itemValue="2" />
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="DONE" itemValue="3" />
        </p:selectOneListbox>
        <h:commandButton action="#{taskView.addNewTask}" value="+"
            update="dash" />
        <div id="dash">
            <p:fieldset id="fieldTasksTodo" legend="TODO">
                <p:dataGrid id="dataGridTasksTodo" var="task"
                    value="#{taskView.allTodoTasks}" columns="1">

                    <p:panel id="task" header="#{task.name}">
                        <h:outputText value="#{task.description}" />
                    </p:panel>
                    <p:draggable for="task" revert="true" />

                </p:dataGrid>
            </p:fieldset>
            <p:droppable for="fieldTasksTodo" datasource="dataGridTasksTodo">
                <p:ajax listener="#{taskView.onTaskDropTodo}"
                    update="fieldTasksTodo fieldTasksDoing fieldTasksDone" />
            </p:droppable>
            <p:fieldset id="fieldTasksDoing" legend="DOING">
                <p:dataGrid id="dataGridTasksDoing" var="task"
                    value="#{taskView.allDoingTasks}" columns="1">

                    <p:panel id="task" header="#{task.name}">
                        <h:outputText value="#{task.description}" />
                    </p:panel>
                    <p:draggable for="task" revert="true" />
                </p:dataGrid>
            </p:fieldset>
            <p:droppable for="fieldTasksDoing" datasource="dataGridTasksTodo">
                <p:ajax listener="#{taskView.onTaskDropDoing}"
                    update="fieldTasksTodo fieldTasksDoing fieldTasksDone" />
            </p:droppable>

            <p:fieldset id="fieldTasksDone" legend="DONE">
                <p:dataGrid id="dataGridTasksDone" var="task"
                    value="#{taskView.allDoneTasks}" columns="1">

                    <p:panel id="task" header="#{task.name}">
                        <h:outputText value="#{task.description}" />
                    </p:panel>
                    <p:draggable for="task" revert="true" />

                </p:dataGrid>
            </p:fieldset>
            <p:droppable for="fieldTasksDone" datasource="dataGridTasksTodo">
                <p:ajax listener="#{taskView.onTaskDropDone}"
                    update="fieldTasksTodo fieldTasksDoing fieldTasksDone" />
            </p:droppable>

        </div>
    </h:form>

</h:body>
</html>
```

TaskView.java (Managed Bean):

```
package br.com.nutrello.dashboard;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.List;

import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;

import org.primefaces.event.DragDropEvent;

@ManagedBean(name = "taskView")
@ViewScoped
public class TaskView implements Serializable{

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 8115685123089539229L;
    private int newTaskState;

    public void init() {
        newTaskState = 1;
    }

    public void addNewTask() {
        HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext()
                .getRequest();
        String newTaskName = request.getParameter("form:newTaskName");
        String newTaskDescription = request.getParameter("form:newTaskDescription");

        Task newTask = new Task(newTaskName, newTaskDescription);

        if (newTaskState == 2) {
            TaskRepository.addTaskDoing(newTask);
        } else if (newTaskState == 3) {
            TaskRepository.addTaskDone(newTask);
        } else {
            TaskRepository.addTaskTodo(newTask);
        }
    }


    public List<Task> getAllTodoTasks() {
        return TaskRepository.getTodoTaskList();
    }

    public List<Task> getAllDoingTasks() {
        return TaskRepository.getDoingTaskList();
    }

    public List<Task> getAllDoneTasks() {
        return TaskRepository.getDoneTaskList();
    }

    public int getNewTaskState() {
        return newTaskState;
    }

    public void setNewTaskState(int newTaskState) {
        this.newTaskState = newTaskState;
    }

    public void onTaskDropTodo(DragDropEvent ddEvent) {
        Task task = ((Task) ddEvent.getData());
        TaskRepository.removeTask(task);
        TaskRepository.addTaskTodo(task);
    }

    public void onTaskDropDoing(DragDropEvent ddEvent) {
        Task task = ((Task) ddEvent.getData());
        TaskRepository.removeTask(task);
        TaskRepository.addTaskDoing(task);
    }

    public void onTaskDropDone(DragDropEvent ddEvent) {
        Task task = ((Task) ddEvent.getData());
        TaskRepository.removeTask(task);
        TaskRepository.addTaskDone(task);       
    }

}
```